# Phone Gap : In App Purchase in Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am new in Phone Gap InApp purchase Android. I build an android application using cordova and I add plugin by using the command

```
cordova plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.purchase --variable BILLING_KEY="MIIB...AQAB"
```

after executing in add plugin in **Config.xml**

```
   <feature name="InAppBillingPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="com.smartmobilesoftware.inappbilling.InAppBillingPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Also **InAppvendingbilling** is automaticaly genrated.

Can any one please help me to how the **index.html** and **js** file is wriiten

1. Need **two button in Index.html**, one for **Managed product** and another for **subscription**.
2. Also after successful payment how I get the **response**